# Liferay error page if at least one portlet is unavailable

Tags: jsf, portlet, liferay, icefaces

I'm trying to setup a custom error page in Liferay portal if at least one portlet fails.

The portal always forwards to `portlet_error.jsp` and display a red zone in the portlet position.

How can I set a redirect or a forward to a page that fills the complete page layout?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Inside your JSP you can redirect to a page in Liferay, which can have just one portlet or the way you want it.

Or write your own servlet which in case of error redirects to page in liferay instead of a JSP

Answer (score -1):

If the response is 404 then you can use this property in portal-ext.properties for add your custom page
layout.friendly.url.page.not.found=/html/portal/page_not_found.html